# Convergence for the serie $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n \ln (1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}})$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

In order to study the convergence of the serie of general term $u_n=(-1)^n \ln (1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}})$, I remark that for $\alpha \leq 0$, the sequence $u_n$ does not tend towards  zero. Suppose that $\alpha > 0$; then $|u_n|\sim n^{-\alpha}$, which means that the serie $\sum u_n$ is absolutly convergent, if and only if, $\alpha > 1$.

Remain the case where $0 < \alpha \leq 1$.

If $0 < \alpha \leq 1$, I have seen in a similar examples that we must  rewrite $u_n$ as
$$
u_n= X_n + v_n
$$ 
where $\sum X_n$ convergent and consequently the series $\sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ are in the same nature.
My question is to find the value of $X_n$ and $v_n$ and conclude.

any helps are welcome.

Comment: Note that that you also have the power of the Alternating Series test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

near $x=0$,

$$\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}(1+\epsilon(x))$$
with
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon(x)=0$$

Your method will work if we had

$$u_n=\ln(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^\alpha})$$

As pointed by Steven, the alternating series test give the answer.
$(|u_n|) $ is decreasing and goes to zero, so the series $\sum (-1)^nu_n$ converges.

Comment: But what about $u_n=(-1)^n \ln (1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}})$!

Comment: @Sanaa look above. it converges as an alternate.